# Google Drive Api can't open all file formats

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

Hi I tried to open some files from Google Drive in andoid app using Google Drive Api with:

```
ResourceClient.openFile(selectedFile.asDriveFile() , DriveFile.MODE_READ_WRITE)
```

My code worked just fine for Word format (docx), but for all ohters format i tried it threw

> com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: This file is not openable.

exception. This exception is nowhere to be found and i really couldn't get rid of it. If anybody can help I would be really grateful.

EDIT: Btw. I claimed metadata for all files successfully.

EDIT 2: Even while using Google samples i could open just Word documents.

Code that I used just in case you would need it:

Signing in to google:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .build();
        signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getApplicationContext(), gso);
        startActivityForResult(signInClient.getSignInIntent(), SING_IN_REQEST_CODE);
```

Geting metadata and files:

```
contentsTask = resourceClient.getMetadata(selectedFile.asDriveResource())
    .continueWithTask(new Continuation<Metadata, Task<DriveContents>>(){
        @Override
        public Task<DriveContents> then(@NonNull Task<Metadata> task) throws Exception {
            if(task.isComplete() && task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Metadata claimed sucessfully");
                if(task.getResult().isEditable())
                    Log.d(TAG, "File is edittable");
                return resourceClient.openFile(selectedFile.asDriveFile() , DriveFile.MODE_READ_WRITE);
            }
            else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Metadata wasn't claimed sucessfully" + task.isComplete());
                return null;
            }
        }
    } ).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DriveContents>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DriveContents driveContents) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "successfully get driveContents");
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "didn't successfully get driveContents", e);
                }
            });
```

EDIT: Issue has been replicated by: https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/issues/70

Comment: Drive API can't open all kinds of files. You can see most of the supported types in [Supported MIME Types](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types). Some supposedly undocumented file types are found [here](https://gist.github.com/javan/7343255).

Comment: Thanks so much for help MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0. Why i have to specify the MIME type i want to open?

Comment: I can't open files includet in the list only paradoxly

Answer (score 0):

So, I left and come back this topic 2 times, but for others: Despide the fact that i didn't find ANY DOCUMENTATION that would say that, Android Drive API (and my friend told me exactly same expirience with Java API) can only download files:

- PDF
- Pictures

and can not download:

- office formats

If anybody would have anything to add (like I overlooked huge documentaion on topic wich formats can you acces with Drive APIs please let me know.-